# remove stopwords/punctuation, tokenize and apply Counter()

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, counter, tokenize

I have a function written to remove stopwords and tokenize as follows:

```
def process(text, tokenizer=TweetTokenizer(), stopwords=[]):    
    text = text.lower()  
    tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(text)
    return [tok for tok in tokens if tok not in stopwords and not tok.isdigit()]
```

I am applying it to a column `tweet['cleaned_text']` as follows:

```
punct = list(string.punctuation)
stopword_list = stopwords.words('english') + punct + ['rt', 'via', '...','“', '”','’']

tf = Counter()
for i  in list(tweet['cleaned_text']):
    temp=process(i, tokenizer=TweetTokenizer(), stopwords=stopword_list)
    tf.update(temp)   
for tag, count in tf.most_common(20):
        print("{}: {}".format(tag, count))
```

The output should be the most common words. Here there are:

```
#blm: 12718
black: 2751
#blacklivesmatter: 2054
people: 1375
lives: 1255
matter: 1039
white: 914
like: 751
police: 676
get: 564
movement: 563
support: 534
one: 534
racist: 532
know: 520
us: 471
blm: 449
#antifa: 414
hate: 396
see: 382
```

As you can see, I am not able to get of rid of the hashtag `#` eventhough it is included in the `punctuation` list (some stopwords are apparent too). #blm and blm are double counted when they should be the same.

I must be missing something in the code.

Comment: you are only filtering so the whole word is kept if it is considered valid.. do you want to do something like `tok.strip("#")` to strip out that character of present?

Comment: Thanks very much, your suggestion is working fine.  However, i am still not filtering out the stopwords. Any suggestion please?

Comment: ok I think I need a bit of clarification, what do you mean by stop words? can you give an example of a stop word in the list and what is showing up that shouldn't be due to stop word? I don't think I fully understand the issue.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen i think you fully understand the issue and your suggestion works great. Stopwords are words that do not add much information and can be removed  when tokenizing. They look like `['i', 'me', 'my', 'myself', 'we', 'our']` . A full list of those words could be found here. `from nltk.corpus import stopwords`  `stopwords.words('english')`

Comment: ok I think the "(some stopwords are apparent too)" threw me off, I wasn't sure if there was more going wrong, glad I was able to help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you process tokens you are keeping the entire word, if you want to strip out a leading `#` you can use `str.strip("#")`

```
def process(text, tokenizer=TweetTokenizer(), stopwords=[]):    
    text = text.lower()  
    tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(text)
    return [tok.strip("#") for tok in tokens if tok not in stopwords and not tok.isdigit()]
```